# Php info differs from server and info.php

Tags: php, apache

I don´t know why but when i type on the server php -v i shows:

> PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 23 2020 00:10:21) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by ionCube Ltd.
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

But if i create a info.php file and see it on the browser it shows only:

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
> Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

As you can see i'm trying to install ioncube extension, if i create an encoded file and execute it from the server directly it works... but if i try to execute the file from the browser it doesn't. Obviusly is something between php and apache server but cant see the issue.

My info.php shows /etc/php.ini as a ini file, and /etc/php.d as route for additional .ini file, i create a file in /etc/php.d that loads the extension and it works with php on the serve but again not when use it on the browser. Its like it was two php one for the server directly and one for php??.

Another thing is that in Additional .ini files parsed, on the server it shows my file created on /etc/php.d/ but not in the info.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the Command Line Interface (php cli) and the PHP version used by Apache or Nginx through your webserver.

Your first command is ran from the command line, which will give you the PHP-CLI version.

Create a file with `phpinfo();` will show you the webserver version.

Comment: Sorry when i say info.php i'm reffering to that, phpinfo(); the phpinfo() when executed shows as additional .ini directory /etc/init.d/ that's where i'm putting my new file that loads the extension, why if phpinfo() says that's the route it does not load the file? but php cli do??

Comment: I'm going to take this as an answer, don't know why but restarting the apache service was not working as expected, after a full system restart it took the changes. Maybe i was restarting wrong the service... o_O. Thanks for taking some time to answer, reggards.

Comment: Simon's answer is incorrect but it *is* quite common for what he says to be the case, so always check for matching major PHP versions (7.3, 7.4 etc.) first. In your case though, one possibility was that you had mod php and restart was doing a graceful restart such that new children were forked but from a parent that wasn't restarted, and so any new config wasn't picked up. If you have a php-fpm pool, that is what needs to be restarted and apache doesn't. Another option is different php.ini files being used. This isn't an exhaustive list but covers the most common config faults.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the .ini files weren't the issue so it must be that i needed to restart php-fpm as you say.